# 1. how can possible in version one export to Word Open Microsoftword

Tags: versionone

1. how can possible in version one export to Word Open Microsoft-word ?

Ability to export to Word just as it is possible to export to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native export to MS Word in VersionOne.  You have to either export from VersionOne to Excel then to Word or use the VersionOne API to write your own export app.  This will not be easy since it will require knowledge of C# or Java SDK.  If you have your own favorite language, you can wrap up the VersionOne Rest API.  It will also require that you understand the VersionOne metadata and the data model. If you are interested, the API documentation is found here https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library